# ASP.net/C# Display dynamic loading message while exporting a results set to Excel

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

i'm going to display loading message which is combined static and dynamic message in c# code behind like,

C#

string message;
 message = strTitle + " is Loading, please wait ";

while generating "export to excel file".
should i use multi thread for this.?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, could you please elaborate or provide your code here.

Comment: thanks for your attention, I will give a case. 
User clicks check one of check boxes and "Export Excel" button,

1. Qurater Report
2. Monthly Report   --> database populated list

while completing exporting excel, i was considering to display "Monthly Report is loading"....
"Monthly" is comes from database.

in this case, should i use threading or javascript ..?
Thanks